# In WPF datagrid need to stop auto selection of cell in currentRow+1 on Enter hit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid; when I hit enter key, current cell selection automatically goes to currentRow +1 cell.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score -1):

To disable selection next row on enter. You can handle DataGrid PreviewKeyDown event like this.

```
private void dg1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {           
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg1" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="dg1_PreviewKeyDown">
```